# Assigning chunk of data from an ipcore output to next ipcore input

Tags: fpga, xilinx-ise

I have a set of 16 data stored in BRAM ipcore. Now I have to fetch first 4 at a time and give it to the next IPcore (say FFT) for further processing. Once done with this, I have to feed the next set of 4 data. Is the situation handled by state machine? OR how can i assign values from one ipcore to the next ipcore ? Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

BRAM  is dual-ported. Simplest is to make a FIFO out of it with one IP core writing and the other IP core  reading.

This will not work for an FFT as that requires a special addressing scheme: the data write order is different from the read order. There you need each IP core to make an address and connect it to the two ports of the BPRAM.

In all cases you need handshaking to guarantee reading only starts after the data has been written of course.